# Grouping JSON DATA

Tags: c#, json, jquery

I am new in JSON architecture, in my code behind (ASP.Net 3.5), from a web method, I am returning an array from a data table, like following:

```
ID | Number
___________

1 | 200  
1 | 300  
2 | 400  
2 | 500  
3 | 600
```

I am returning this table in an array to JSON Object.
What I want to do is to structure data as follows using JQuery:

```
<div id="1">ID = 1</div>
    <div id="11">200</div>
    <div id="12">300</div>
</div>
<div id="2">ID = 2</div>
    <div id="21">400</div>
    <div id="22">500</div>
</div>
<div id="3">ID = 3</div>
    <div id="31">600</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the rendering itself, I would recommend a javascript template library such as [jsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender). As for the JSON formatting, your best bet is to group the data on the server side and have each property contain an array, so your JSON would look like this:

```
var data = {
    "1": ["200", "300"],
    "2": ["400", "500"],
    "3": ["600"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it manually, using an object to group your values.
Say your JSON object deserializes to this:

```
var myTable = [{ID: 1, Number:200}, {ID: 1, Number:300}, {ID: 2, Number:400}, {ID: 2, Number:500}, {ID: 3, Number:600}]
```

Then this code would group the values:

```
var myObject = {};
$.each(myTable, function() {
    if (!myObject[this.ID]) myObject[this.ID] = [];
    myObject[this.ID].push(this.Number);
}
```

Then you should build your html code structure... Something like:

```
var myHtml = $("");
$.each(myObject, function(ID, Numbers) {
    if (Numbers) {
        var divId = $("<div></div>").attr("id", ID);
        $.each(Numbers, function(index, number) {
            divId.append($("<div></div>").attr("id", ID.toString() + (index+1).toString()).html(number));
        }
        divId.appendTo(myHtml);
    }
}
```

Note that the in your question html is not valid, it has too many `</div>` closing tags, so you adapt the code depending on what you need.